# Inconsistent vh unit behaviour

Tags: css, viewport-units

I have a pseudo element that appears on hover with:

```
height: 0.4vh;
```

The height doesn't change, only the width does. For some reason, however, under certain conditions the heights of different pseudo elements differ (both of the darker lines here have `height: 0.4vh`):

[image: vh unit weirdness]

I put up this fiddle to demonstrate, but realise that it depends on the viewport height whether this weirdness happens:
https://jsfiddle.net/vuw693La/

I am having this issue on Chromium and Firefox. Am I doing something wrong or is there no way to be "pixel perfect" with `vh` units?

Comment: Naturally rounding is gonna be involved in one way or another unless the viewport height can be perfectly divided accordingly into the values you are using. And this can result in different rendering for the "same" elements in different places as well, because the sum of all fractions does not necessarily add up to a 100%, so "something's gotta give" in one place or another. @jack's answer is the best and most practical solution IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe I see your point regarding rounding, thanks. I would have thought that `calc(100vh * 0.004)` would have given me a consistent height in that case but no such luck.

Comment: `calc(100vh * 0.004)` still can only work with what `100vh` _actually_ are. Take a viewport height of say some arbitrary 767 pixels, then times .004 still gives you a result of 3.068 "pixels." Now, sub-pixel rendering as a most times moderately adequate counter measure left aside, if we work with "whole" pixels only, that .068 fraction of pixels that occur in multiples places still have to go somewhere. Round it down to 3 pixels in X places, will leave you with at least 1 place where is gotta be 4 instead most of the time (simplyfied, but I think you'll get my drift.)

Comment: @CBroe I get that and so I can see why rounding inconsistently with relative units is useful, I just would have thought that the rendering engine would round consistently with a calc function.

Comment: My point is, it can not necessarily do that in some situations. It doesn't happen because it is "useful", but because it is a mathematical necessity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some imprecision in browser renderings, especially when percentages or viewport units come into play. In this case, I'd consider whether it's actually worth it to make the height of those lines tied to the viewport. It seems limited to within a few pixels of variance for most screen sizes; maybe either set one size for it, or set static sizes at several breakpoints to gradually scale it up.

```
.icon_piece::after { height: 1px; }

// tweak breakpoints to whatever works best for your design
@media (min-height: 600px) { 
  icon_piece::after { height: 2px; } 
}

@media (min-height: 900px) {
  icon_piece::after { height: 3px; }
}
```

Comment: It's strange to me that there should be imprecision when the selector is the same for all of the blocks. Surely the browser should only calculate the unit once (and then recalculate if/when the viewport changes)?

Comment: You'll notice the same thing sometimes with things like percentage-based gradients; not sure exactly why, but I'm not an expert on rendering engines.

Comment: Well, if you want "pixel perfect", use pixels. (And even that isn't an absolute guarantee of course, with zooming, sub-pixel rendering etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers have inconsistencies when using viewport units, specially smaller than 1vw or 1vh.

The way I solved this problem is by assigning larger units (multiplying them by 4 for example) and then using `transform: scale(0.25);` to get the element back to the desired size.

This is not a straightforward solution as you probably will have to rearrange your code to make it work but I couldn't find any other workaround.