# Vh units not perfect on absolute position elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a webpage that has multiple different boxes that are positioned absolute. I'm having an issue when I use this css:

```
height: 20vh;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20vh;
width:100vw;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left 0px;
position: absolute;
```

It will overlap with this element:

```
text-align: center;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
flex-direction: row;
width: 94vw;
height: 5vh;
font-size: 5vh;
position: absolute;
top: 20vh;
```

I would assume that putting an element `20vh` away from the top would prevent the elements from overlapping. It is only a little bit but I'm positioning all elements this way so that the site stays practically the same in any container while fitting within the screen. Is there anyway to fix this overlap?

Also all of my other css is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: This is a duplicate: [Inconsistent vh unit behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322747/inconsistent-vh-unit-behaviour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent vh unit behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322747/inconsistent-vh-unit-behaviour)